# Redefine a class or function

Tags: c#, vbscript, msscriptcontrol

I have to add a VBScript interface to our C# app and have completed this with `ScriptControlClass` (MS Scripting Engine). However, I am not too familiar with VBS and can't find a solution to this:

If I define a class then decide to make a change to that class, when I run the code for the class a second time I get the error:

> Name redefined

Example:

1. Define a `Class` (ex: `Class test .... End Class`)
2. "Compile" (from C# code, call `ScriptControlClass.AddCode(code_for_class)`)
3. Make a change to the class's code
4. "Compile" again - get error here

How do I "undefine" the class before trying to compile?

Also, I am not asking about how to`Dim` or `Redim` an object of that class. I want to modify the class code.

Answer (score 1):

Script code is not "compiled", it is executed when you call `AddCode()`

All of the code you add is known by the scriptcontrol until you do `Reset()`. Resetting makes the scriptcontrol remove all the code that has been added.

So you'll first have to `Reset()` before you add the code for the same class again.

Comment: I was hoping to do it without `Reset()`. I just want to "re-compile" that one class, not reset the whole script engine. (I'm just using the term "compile" for what the script engine does to turn my code into something it can execute). I can "re-compile" `sub`s and `function`s with no error.